# Blazor Server - How to disable a control inside component?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I try to show and disable a button by adding "disabled" class in a component (pre-hidden) but failed - it's not working. Where I did wrong ?

Component Button :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary @disabled">Disable Me</button>
</div>

@code {
    string _password;
    string disabled = "";

    public void Disable()
    {
        disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

Index.razor :

```
@page "/"

<h1>How to disable button in component ?</h1>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ShowAndDisableButton">Show and disable button</button>

@if (show)
{
    <ButtonComponent @ref="button"/>
}

@code
{
    ButtonComponent button = new();
    bool show = false;

    void ShowAndDisableButton()
    {
        show = true;
        button.Disable();
    }
}
```

UPDATED : if I change the ShowAndDisableButton code to

```
async Task ShowAndDisableButton()
{
    show = true;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)); // add this, wait for a while
    button.Disable();
}
```

and change button code in index.razor to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="()=>ShowAndDisableButton()">Show and disable button</button>
```

it works. but I don't know why and don't want to use such way, are there any proper way?

Comment: You need to do two things: (1) change your variable; (2) update the UI.  When a Task completes, the UI updates automatically.  When a void method completes, it does not-- you'll have to invoke StateHasChanged();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `button.Disable();` does not cause the normal rerendering.

And it is an overcomoplicated way of doing things.

In the page:

```
@if (show)
{
    <ButtonComponent Disabled="!show" />
}

@code
{
    //ButtonComponent button = new();
    bool show = false;

    void ShowAndDisableButton()
    {
        show = true;
        //button.Disable();
    }
}
```

and the button itself:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" disabled="Disabled">Disable Me</button>
</div>

@code {
    string _password;
//    string disabled = "";

    [Parameter] public bool Disabled {get; set; }
 
}
```

But you won't be able to use this button.

Comment: it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use disabled="@disabledState"
Where disabledState is a boolean

Comment: same problem, not working for me.